# Trying to pass request image from Django to Python script

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, request

Im creating a project where i'm sending a Request with an image to my Django local server. The image is received and saved which works fine.

However, after receiving the image i am trying to pass the file to my python Script. There it should run the script with the image and return data back to the user.

Im stuck as i can't seem to pass the image filename to the python script and therefore run the script with the image.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

The many (#):s are my attempts to do this.

**views.py**

```
class ImageViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
               mixins.CreateModelMixin,
               generics.GenericAPIView):
"""
    Upload image (Save and Run Script)
   """

parser_classes = (JSONParser, MultiPartParser, FormParser,)
queryset = UploadImageTest.objects.all()
serializer_class = ImageSerializer

def output(self, request):

    imagename = request.FILES['image']
    #imagename = request.data['image']
    #imagename = models.ImageField
    #imagename = request.FILES['image'].name
    #imagename = UploadImageTest.image
    print(imagename)

    #self.request.FILES['image']
    #inp = request.data['image']
    inp = request.FILES.get(imagename)
    out = run([sys.executable,'//Users/macbookpro//TestAPI//venv//TestImageScript.py',inp],shell=False,stdout=PIPE)
    print(out)

    return {"status": "Success", "output": str(out)}
```

**Serializer.py**

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = UploadImageTest
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'image')
```

**models.py**

```
class UploadImageTest(models.Model):
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
description = models.TextField(blank=True)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return "{}".format(self.name)
```

**Python Script**

```
file_name = sys.argv[1]
print(file_name)


img = cv2.imread("file_name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
request.FILES.get['image'].filename
```

As per documentation of ImageField [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField), it inherits all attributes of [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField) which contains an attribute `filename` (Don't forget to see the description of this field in documentation)

**EDIT**

You can try `name` attribute instead:

```
f = request.FILES['image_url']
print(dir(f))   # This shows everything we can do by using this variable
print("filename : ", f.name)
```

**EDIT:**

To get the modified uploaded filename you can first let the object saved and then retrieve the filename. You may try something like this:
(Assuming there is model named a `SomeModel` and having an attribute `image_url` which is ImageField)

```
someModel = SomeModel.objects.get(id=id)
data = {'image_url': image_url}
serialized_model = SomeModelSerializer(someModel, data=data, partial=True)
if not serialized_model.is_valid():
    raise ParseError(serialized_model.errors)
serialized_model.save()
print(serialized_model.data.get('image_url')) # <--- Here you go
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However it does not work. Maybe there is something else that i am missing.

Comment: Thanks for the support. request.FILES.get('image').name prints and fetches the filename however it always grabs "random.png". Django automatically renames the files creating a unique filename every-time. I am unable to fetch the newly generated filename. It always grabs "random.png".